# Ideals of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, solution-verification

I had the following - apparently straightforward - question on one of my past assignments:

> Show that a field has no other ideals except $\{0\}$ and the field itself.

This was the proof I gave:

> Let $I \ne \{0\}$ be an ideal of a field $R$. There must therefore
>   exist a nonzero $a \in I$, and so for every $b \in R$ we have
>   $a(a^{-1} b) \in I$ by definition of an ideal since $a \in R$ is
>   invertible so $a^{-1} b \in R$.
>
> It follows $b \in I$ for all $b \in R$ so
>   $I = R$, and therefore $\{ 0 \}$ and $R$ are the only ideals of $R$.

But when I got it back the part "$a \in R$ is invertible and $a^{-1} b \in R$" was underlined saying it "does not work". But why not? As far as I know all nonzero elements in a field are invertible under multiplication, multiplication in a field is closed, and multiplication in a field is also associative. What has gone wrong?

Can someone look over my solution and explain where I made a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: It seems your proof was already complete when you showed $b\in I$. Id show that $I$ contains$1_{R}$ instead.

Comment: The proof is fine. One might want to show that $\{0\}$ and the field are indeed ideals, but the grader seems to some other (invisible to me) concern.

Comment: Maybe they thought you said $a^{-1}b \in I$... either way the grader is the one at fault.

Comment: Usually we consider left ideals... So, when you have written $a(a^{-1}b)$ they assume that you are considering $a^{-1}b\in I$ and $a\in R$... I guess that is the reason why that underline... But you are considering right ideal.. so what ever you have done is correct...

Comment: I hope you have spoken to your marker/teacher/professor and asked for more details.  As a simple matter of courtesy you should if possible do that first, then ask elsewhere (e.g. here) if their comments are not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You were done the second you said $a(a^{-1}b) \in I$. Since $b$ was chosen to be arbitrary, it meant you had just shown $R \subseteq I$ at which point you could have concluded that $R = I$.

Perhaps they made the same mistake I made the first time reading it through, I saw

> by definition of ideal since $a \in R$ is invertible then so **is** $a^{-1}b \in R$

which of course isn't true if you had chosen $b = 0$.

But that's just speculation.

It appears your grader just made a mistake. It happens.